# Can't Subtract player hp

Tags: python

I am trying to Subtract player hp.

Here is my code example:

```
class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 100

    def check_death(self):
    ....

p = player()
p.hp - 10
print p.hp
```

But it is printing 100 so no Subtraction is done how can i fix it?
THX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
p.hp - 10
```

calculates a new value and then throws it away, because you haven't told Python to put the result anywhere. Either do:

```
p.hp = p.hp - 10
```

or Python supports the following shorthand for the above:

```
p.hp -= 10
```